# Checking request get parameter in Django template

Tags: python, django, get, request

I'm checking a request.GET parameter in Django template. I'm pasting a portion of it:

```
<dd>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right {% if request.GET.order %}{% ifequal request.GET.order 'price-asc' %}active{% endifequal %}{% endif %}"></i> <a href="{%url_add_replace request 'order' 'price-asc'%}">Order by price (Asc)</a>
</dd>
```

As you see there is also a custom template tag named add_replace. It's basically adding the specified GET parameter to url. I don't think it makes problem.

My question is about something else. This code generates log at DEBUG level. And i'm trying to get rid of it. The log is below. I think there must be sth more suitable to check if a get parameter does exists or not. I can do it in views like:

```
get_dict = request.GET.copy()

if get_dict.__contains__('order'):
    get_order = get_dict.__getitem__('order')
else:
    get_order = None
```

But when i check it in the template, below log occurs:

```
DEBUG 2016-07-08 22:07:43,789 base 29571 140656761874496 Exception while resolving variable 'order' in template 'category.html'. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 83, in __getitem__
    list_ = super(MultiValueDict, self).__getitem__(key) KeyError: 'order'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 883, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key)) django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'order'"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 891, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit) AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'order'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 898, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'order'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [order] in '<QueryDict: {}>'
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I'm adding the custom template tag code:

```
@register.simple_tag(name='url_add_replace')
def url_add_replace(request, field, value):

    dict = request.GET.copy()

    dict.__setitem__(field, value)

    return u"?%s" % (dict.urlencode())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with writing another custom tag:

```
@register.simple_tag(name='active_request_get')
def active_request_get(request, key, value):

    dict = request.GET.copy()

    if dict.__contains__(key):

        if dict.get(key, default=None) == value:
            return 'active'

    return ''
```

I replaced this:

```
<dd>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right {% if request.GET.order %}{% ifequal request.GET.order 'price-asc' %}active{% endifequal %}{% endif %}"></i> <a href="{%url_add_replace request 'order' 'price-asc'%}">Order by price (Asc)</a>
</dd>
```

with this:

```
<dd>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right {% active_request_get request 'order' 'price-asc' %}"></i> <a href="{%url_add_replace request 'order' 'price-asc'%}">Order by price (Asc)</a>
</dd>
```

So i check the GET parameters as i want.

Answer (score 12):

I think a custom template tag is overkill for this. The following template logic should work without triggering any debug logs:

```
{% if 'order' in request.GET %}
    {% ifequal request.GET.order 'price-asc' %}active{% endifequal %}
{% endif %}
```

The difference between this and your original code is that the outer `if` block is checking for the existence of `order` in `GET`, rather than evaluating the truthiness of `GET.order`.

Comment: thanks for the idea. i'll try it as soon as possible and share the results.